# AppleScript: error when trying to retreive server's disk

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to test if a server (my NAS) is mounted. I can't use *disk's name* because AppleScript returns names of the NAS' volumes, and not the NAS' name, so I tried:

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell application "System Events" to set theVolumes to every disk
    repeat with thisVolume in theVolumes
        set isLocal to thisVolume's local volume
        if (not isLocal) then
            set thisDisk to thisVolume's server -- > unable to coerce the data to the desired type
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Script Debugger returns the following error: *unable to coerce the data to the desired type*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code belongs completely to `System Events`. The Finder is not involved at all.

The error occurs because you try to resolve `System Events` terminology in a `Finder` tell block. Replace `Finder` with  `System Events` and remove the `tell` part in the second line.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theVolumes to every disk
    repeat with thisVolume in theVolumes
        set isLocal to thisVolume's local volume
        if (not isLocal) then
            set thisDisk to thisVolume's server -- > unable to coerce the data to the desired type
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```